# What would you use for non-recurring billing with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, billing

I have a bit of a conundrum with my Rails application. It looks like the model we are going to use for billing is per-use as opposed to a subscription basis (at least initially). While we've already implemented Recurly's Transparent Post API (great product), it's likely overkill.

We could simply establish a free plan with no monthly charge and then initiate one time transactions. This satisfies the level of PCI Compliance we are looking for and also allows returning customers to have their credit card information stored by a third party.

To further complicate things, there may be a requirement in the future for subscription based plans in addition to the per-use billing. I am looking for some advice about whether to stay with the recurring billing platform or whether I might want to simply use ActiveMerchant, not store credit cards and deal with the change in PCI Compliance (onus is on us and not a third party). Also wondering if there is another tool that handles one-time repeatable transactions without having a subscription plan?

Answer (score 2):

You could use ActiveMerchant with Authorize.net CIM or Braintree to store the card info for you (for the PCI compliance) and run transactions for whatever amount at whatever time based on the token you would get back from either of those.  That wouldn't preclude from adding on the recurring billing later -- you would just start charging against those stored tokens on an automated basis.

The [SaaS Rails Kit](http://railskits.com/saas/) (which I wrote) takes this approach for doing both the recurring billing and one-off transactions.